# Is there a XAML formatter to replace the need for the closing tag?

Tags: xaml

I need to reduce the clutter in my XAML code, so I'd like to get rid of unnecessary closing tags for tags without a body.

I tried the XAML Styler extension and it does that, but it also messes up the attributes of the tag, reordering them and allowing only one attribute per line, which, in my opinion, is even worse than just having the closing tags

A very common case would be Grid's rows/columns definitions:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

(The closing tags are added automatically by VisualStudio)

The XAML formatter I'm looking for would fix things like indentation and turn the code above into this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it fits your needs, but you can do a regex replace for these.

Press Ctrl-Shift-H for replace.
Find what is:

```
<(\w+)><\/\1>
```

Replace with:

```
<$1/>
```

Of course you should check 'Use Regular Expressions'.

This is just quick and dirty replace, that is not aware of whitespaces and such but the regex can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out XAML Styler is configurable, (`Tools > Options > XAML Styler`) so I can use it just to solve my problem and nothing more by disabling all the other stuff.

Info regarding configuration can be found here https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/wiki/Configuration